# g++ alternative to Java's @SuppressWarnings annotation

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, suppress-warnings, gcc-warning

In Java, if there is a warning that should be ignored we can suppress warnings on it like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void functionCalledExternally(){
    //code
}
```

What I can use to suppress a specific instance of a specific warning in g++?

Comment: You might want to read about [the diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It looks like, via the push/pop mechanism, that what you linked can accomplish what I am asking about. It sounds like an answer to me :) (although some less clunky syntax would be preferable).

Comment: @Danh I am asking about g++.